# JSON value printed as "undefined" in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON data with which I want to create a list of links. The keys in the JSON object are rendered fine, but the values corresponding to those keys print "undefined" on the browser.

```
var html = "<ul>";

$.ajax({
  url: fullpath,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    for (var pageid in data.query.pages) {
      console.log(pageid, pageid.title, pageid.extract);
      html += "<li><a href=\"" + wikisearchurl + pageid + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + pageid.title + '</br>' + pageid.extract + "</a></li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    $('#para').html(html);
  }
});
```

[image: Here's the output]

The links when clicked take me to the correct pages, meaning the "href" attribute is set just fine. The problem is only with the link text.

Comment: What does your console output?

Comment: can you add a sample response that is received from the server from the `ajax` call

Comment: Try data.query.pages[pageid].title

Comment: you `pageid.title + '</br>' + pageid.extract ` does not seem to have the values show the response that is received from the server

Comment: It's hard to know exactly where the problem is without knowing what the returned structure is supposed to look like, but at a glance a `for in` loop will give you back a key (or index) not an object. So it might be that it's supposed to be `data.query.pages[pageid].title` instead of just `pageid.title`

Comment: @SanketPatel is right thats it

Comment: What does console.log(data) show?

Comment: @SanketPatel it worked.. thanks a lot.

Comment: @aaronjkrause awesome explanation. Just one more doubt. Why does "data.query.pages.pageid.title" generate an error (Cannot read property 'title' of undefined), whereas "data.query.pages[pageid].title" works fine? Aren't they supposed to be the same?

Comment: @SomeshThakur  If the `pageid` in the brackets were a string they would be the same but in this case they're different. When use dot notation it looks specifically for the key name after the dot. When you use bracket notation it evaluates the expression in the brackets and then looks for a key based on the results. So `data.query.pages.pageid` is looking for a property `pageid` on the object at `data.query.pages`. `data.query.pages[pageid]` is looking for a key equal to whatever `pageid` *evaluates to*. In this case it looks like it's a variable storing an index.

Comment: @aaronjkrause super.. Got it now.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a "(for x in y)"-like loop, it's clear you're looping through an array and not an object. Therefore "pageid" corresponds to the index for each element in the array.

To access elements in an array, use instead:

```
data.query.pages[pageid].title
```

and

```
data.query.pages[pageid].extract
```

That should give you the info you're trying to get.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! :